# How to access orca screen reader and voiceover to make them speak some texts in c#

Tags: c#, accessibility, voiceover, screen-readers, orca

So I want to make my c# class library (.net 4.5) speak some texts to the screen readers. Now I have made it narrate a text in windows using the AccessibleOutput Nuget package but I can't seem to find anything for voiceover or orca screen reader.

Now I can go ahead and use a TTS but visually impaired people prefer screen readers over TTS.

[Stardew Access](https://github.com/stardew-access/stardew-access) - this is the code.

Comment: The github link (stardew access) is bad

Comment: I'm the author of UniversalSpeech, a library that can make speak Jaws, NVDA, WindowsEye and Cobra under Windows. I admit I would also be greatly interested to port my C library.

Comment: I love writing in plain C, @QuentinC

Comment: @slugolicious: I chose C for a precise reason: almost any programming languages can use C libraries, while you restrict potential users to a specific language otherwise.

Comment: AFter some search, it looks like one possible answer for linux is [speech dispatcher](https://freebsoft.org/speechd)

Comment: Took my first class in C while a senior in college in the previous millennium, which helped me land my first job (which lasted several decades) because the software company had just started writing their products in C.  Great language and totally unrelated to this accessibility question.